# nested attributes + multi select: Couldn't find Collection with ID=["1", "2", "3"] for Product with ID=?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a many-many relationship with `collections` is a multi-select field for `product`

products_controller.rb

```
def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.collections.build
    @product.categories.build
    @product
end

def create
   @product = Product.new(product_params)
   ...
end

private
def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:product_id, :name, :price, :popularity, 
        collections_attributes: [ id: [] ])
end
```

products model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :product_id, uniqueness: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collections, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections, reject_if: ->(attributes){ attributes['id'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

products view

```
    <%= form.fields_for :collections do |fc| %>
      <%= fc.label :collections %>
      <%= fc.select(:id, Collection.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, 
                    { include_blank: true, include_hidden: false }, {multiple: true}) %>
    <% end %>
```

View will look like this as user has the option to select multiple collections
[image: view]

However, when I post to `/create`, it says

[image: error]

Log for `products_params.inspect`

[image]

Not quite sure what's wrong with it. Is it because `ids` can't take an array? If that so what is a solution for it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**
whole product form. Please ignore `product_id` as it's not a primary key.

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.label :product_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :product_id %>

   
    <%= form.fields_for :collections do |fc| %>
      <%= fc.label :collections %>
      <%= fc.select(:id, Collection.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, 
                    { include_blank: true, include_hidden: false }, {multiple: true}) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole form? You're showing only a part of it

Comment: @Joel_Blum No worries. Just updated

Comment: Are you sure form_with is getting an instance of a new product?

Comment: @Joel_Blum, yes. In new.html I have `<%= render 'form', product: @product %>`. and I included the new method in the post for the controller.

Comment: @AustinP I might be wrong, but shouldn't there be like this?
`params.require(:product).permit(:product_id, :name, :price, :popularity, collections_attributes: [ :id ])`

Comment: @BorysPylhun i have tried with `[ :id ]`. The problem with that is since multi-select will return you an array, and if it's just `[ :id ]` itself, params will not accept the array. As a result, it will simply ignore the whole array and doesn't take any `ids` from the collections_attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need nested attributes to just associate records. This is an extremely common misconception. In fact using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections` would cause you to alter the `collections` table instead of your `products_collections` join table!

Instead just use the `collection_ids=` setter created by `has_and_belongs_to_many :collections`.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :product_id, uniqueness: true
  # has_and_belongs_to_many is always optional...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collections
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>
  # ...

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :product_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :product_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :collection_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:collection_ids, Collection.all, :id, :name, multiple: true) %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(
     :product_id, :name, :price, :popularity, 
     collection_ids: [] # allows an array of values
   )
end
```

This will automatically add/delete join rows depending on the contents of the array.

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` is only necessary if you need to pass attributes for another model (or join model) in a single form submission. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` can't actually be used to manipulate join table rows for `has_and_belongs_to_many` assocatiation as there is no model to accept nested attributes for. You would need to use `has_many through:` instead.

Comment: > accepts_nested_attributes_for is only necessary if you need to pass attributes for another model (or join model) in a single form submission . But that is exactly what he wants to do no?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really know the use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. So as I understand the only use case of it is to modify another table using the same form.

Comment: @Joel_Blum note that I wrote join model - not join table. And it's only really relevant if you need to pass some sort of additional data that describes the relationship. If you're just linking A and B on C  then no.